# Error creating bean name "t"

Tags: spring

I am new to Spring and trying some program using Spring while doing a simple program I am getting following error

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 't' defined in class path resource [resources/spring.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'driver' of bean class [beans.Test]: Bean property 'driver' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 't' defined in class path resource [resources/spring.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'driver' of bean class [beans.Test]: Bean property 'driver' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at test.Client.main(Client.java:10)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'driver' of bean class [beans.Test]: Bean property 'driver' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.createNotWritablePropertyException(BeanWrapperImpl.java:243)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.processLocalProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:437)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:280)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564)
    ... 13 more
```

this is my Spring.xml file

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<beans>
  <bean id="t" class="beans.Test">
    <property name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/emp"/>
    <property name="user" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="root123"/>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

Test.java

```
package beans;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;

public class Test implements InitializingBean, DisposableBean
{
   private String driver,url,user,password;
   private Connection con;

   public void setDriver(String driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}
   public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}
   public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
}
   public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

    @Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception 
   {
      Class.forName(driver);
      con= DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
      System.out.println("Connection Opened");
   }

    public void insert(int id,int age, String first, String last )throws Exception
    {
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into employee vvalues(?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setInt(1, id);
        ps.setInt(2, age);
        ps.setString(3, first);
        ps.setString(4, last);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Successfully Inserted");

    }

   @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception 
    {
        con.close();
       System.out.println("Connection Closed");
    }

}
```

Main()

```
  package test;

import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Client 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext cap=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("resources/spring.xml");

  }

}
```

What could be the cause of this?

I am using **Eclipse Oxygen** basically this is using some concepts of JDBC using which I am trying to test Spring life cycle properties.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need a getter for property Driver `Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?`.

Add

```
 public String getDriver() {
    return driver;
}
```

same for other properties.